Error when working with Airflow and Jupyter Notebook
I have installed Airflow on wsl. I picked up the service and wrote the first dag, I wrote the dag in jupiter notebook, which I also installed on wsl in the necessary environment. But Airflow does not see my dag even when working out the following command: airflow dogs list-import-errors. Returns the following error:enter image description here
Although I did not create the file untiled-chekpoint.py - jupiter saves this type of checkpoint itself, I can't figure out how to solve this problem, please tell me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I deleted this file. But in web interface of Apache Dag is invisible

This seems to be responding to an automated comment rather than solving the original problem. Rather than adding answers if you don't have a solution, it would be better to edit the original text of your question.
